# JSP how to manage welcome-file-list?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How can i redirect users to one of the pages accordingly his domain name? 
**web.xml**

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>now_see_this.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>Another.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- make a filter (`javax.servlet.Filter`)
- map it to `/`
- check `request.getServerName()` and compare with a predefined list of domains
- `request.getRequestDispatcher("/someIndex.jsp").forward()` depending on the domain.

However, it looks like a strange use-case, because the user will still be able to access the index files for other domains if he knows them (if they are not hidden in `WEB-INF`). But without knowing your requirements I can't suggest a better solution.

Comment: If i have a single Domain and same web.xml then what page will be served to the user ? (In case if always the first page will be served then what is the need to have multiple entries in welcome-file-list?)