# how to set different welcome-file for each group?

Tags: jsf

i have default welcome-file for all users but i need each welcome file for each group :

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>EspaceAdmin</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>administrateur</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint2</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>EspaceDrapage</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/drapage/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>chefdequipedrapage</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

    </security-constraint>
```

here i have 2 groups how i can set for each group a new welcome-file ??

Comment: i need to delete the default welcome-file-list ???

Comment: You can use a filter on *faces/index.xhtml* that will redirect the user based on its role. Note that this is very strange since you won't know the user role if there was no previous authentication and validation step.

Comment: how i can user the redirect depend of the user rule ??

Comment: i found this solution but i dont know how to apply it http://stackoverflow.com/a/4821401/2405945 any one can help ?

Comment: That's pretty much what my comment said. Please refer to [StackOverfloe Servlet Filter wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) to have an example of how to use a filter.

Comment: can you write an answer to my example to help me and other visitors that gonna face the same problem :D.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution worked for me : i created a managed bean contain :

```
public String Login() {
        try {
            message="";
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            request.login(username, password);

            if(request.isUserInRole("administrateur"))
            { setGroupname("administrateur");
                return "/admin/adminHome.xhtml";}

            else if(request.isUserInRole("chefdtype1"))
            {setGroupname("cheftype1");
                return "/type1/type1Home.xhtml";}

            else if(request.isUserInRole("cheftype2"))
            {setGroupname("cheftype2");
                return "/type2/type2Home.xhtml";}

            else {
                message= "Either Login or Password is wrong";
                return "/index.xhtml";
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            message= "Either Login or Password is wrong";
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Votre login ou votre mot de passe est incorrect.", ""));
        }
        return null;
    }
```